# Delete duplicate rows Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I should delete duplicate rows from my table.
My table structure is :
ClientId-GiftId-Invoice-Quantite

Example of Duplicate Rows :

```
Example 1:
 1. C1-G1-Inv1-1
 2. C1-G1-Inv1-0
 3. C1-G1-NULL-NULL
```

Expected Result :  2 AND 3 should be deleted

Example 2:

```
 1. C2-G1-NULL-NULL
 2. C2-G1-NULL-NULL
 3. C2-G1-NULL-NULL
```

Expected Result : any row is accepted

My delete query is :

```
WITH CTE AS(
   SELECT ClientID,GiftID,Invoice,Quantity,
       RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY ClientID,GiftID,Invoice,Quantity ORDER BY 
 ClientID,GiftID,Invoice)
   FROM #RowsToDelete
)
Delete FROM CTE where RN > 1
```

i'm new with use of ROW_NUMBER() Function and i think i didn't figure how to use it properly
Thanks in advance

Comment: In the first example, why should 2 and 3 be deleted?  In the second example, why should any row be accepted?

Comment: the reason is that the gifts could be attributed but not consumed by the client.

Comment: I don't think you're understanding what the `PARTITION BY` does, as you appear to be partitioning, and ordering on every columns apart from `quantity`.The columns in the `PARTITION BY` don't need to be in the `ORDER BY`. The `PARTITION BY` is the distinct groups you want to create, and the `ORDER BY` the order you want those distinct groups in.

Comment: i'm still learning the ROW_NUMBER() function and this is my first time using it. Yes this is the problem, thanks for the quick reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your partition by and order by clause like below -

```
WITH CTE AS(
   SELECT ClientID,GiftID,Invoice,Quantity,
       RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ClientID,GiftID ORDER BY Quantite desc)
   FROM #RowsToDelete
)
Delete FROM CTE where RN > 1
```